# How to run one Jenkins stage on a different agent

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile with a bunch of stages. Agent is defined at top level like so:

```
agent {
    label 'windows'
}
```

There are a pool of agents labelled `windows`. I'd like to  make one of the parallel stages to run on a different agent that the whole pipeline, but from the same agent `windows` pool.

Not sure if I should use [Lockable Resources](https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources/) plugin or `agent{}` option can be used in some way.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Might be not very optimal solution, but it should allow you to split the build to different nodes.

`agent` can be used on pipeline level, as well as on stage level.

You can introduce two labels (I assume that you have two stages running in parallel) e.g. `windows-pool-1` and `windows-pool-2` and make sure all your `windows` are split to this two groups. Then just use different pools for these stages and those will run on different machines guaranteed.

There's even an example in [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) (here's a bit shorter adjusted version):

```
pipeline {
    agent 'windows'
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Stage') {
            parallel {
                stage('Run on pool 1') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows-pool-1"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "do stuff on 1"
                    }
                }
                stage('Run on pool 2') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows-pool-2"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "do stuff on 2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```